# C++ dynamic type - overriding methods

Tags: c++, subclassing, overriding

Normal overriding would work this way:

```
class Fruit {
public:
    string color();
};

string Fruit::color() {
    return "Unkown";
};

class Apple : public Fruit {
public:
    string color();
};

string Apple::color() {
    return "Green";
};
```

Now, you'ld call this like:

```
Apple *apple = new Apple();
std::cout << apple->color();
```

This will output `Green`, which is correct! However, running it in the following situation (which is just an example, of course):

```
Apple *apple = new Apple();
printHealthy(apple);

// Method printHealthy:

void printHealthy(Fruit *fruit) {
    std::cout << fruit->color();
};
```

This will output `Unkown`, which I can understand, since you're casting Apple to Fruit, and thus 'replace' its methods. But how can I still get to know its real color?
Requirements:

- I need to know what its real color is.
- I cannot rely on the `Apple`-class. There will be lots of more `Apple`'s, which are assigned on the go.
- every `Apple`-class (eg. `Tomato`, they have different names of course) is a subclass of `Fruit`.
- not every class implements all methods. For example, there might be an `Apple` which color *is* 'unkown', so it doesn't override that method and instead, run `Fruit`'s method.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Mark the function `virtual` in the base class.

```
class Fruit {
public:
    virtual string color();
};
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it works :D! As a PHP and ObjC dev I started learning C++ yesterday and it's just such a wonderful language, it combines all the good things about Obj-C and PHP!

Answer (score 5):

You forgot `virtual`. Add the `virtual` keyword to the *declaration* of `color` and your code will print the correct colour. C++ will only perform a dynamic lookup on functions declared as `virtual`.

Answer (score 2):

The `color` method should be a virtual method.

Right now, the `color` method is not virtual. The compiler decides at compile time which method to call. What you want is to do this at runtime, based on the actual type of the class.